# Turn off Pygame alpha

Tags: python, pygame, alphablending

I have a computer game I'm working on, and I'm wanting to give the user an option to turn off alpha compositing for speed purposes. Rather than doing checks everywhere, does Pygame have a global option to say "Don't use alpha" such that it would just ignore all my calls to set_alpha and the likes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the pygame docs I would say *"no, there is no global way to disable alpha"*.
However there are at least two *'local'* ways to do it:

- First would be to subclass pygame.Surface and provide your own implementation of set_alpha
  which in turn could honor your global alpha settings.
- Second one is a bit more tricky as it depends on the pixel-format in use.
  To quote the pygame docs:

> **Surface.set_alpha**
>   *set the alpha value for the whole surface*
>   *[...]*
>   This value is different than the per pixel Surface alpha. If the Surface format contains
>   per pixel alphas, then this alpha value will be ignored. If the Surface contains per pixel
>   alphas, setting the alpha value to None will disable the per pixel transparency.
>   *[...]*

With this you could provide two sets of textures:

- one with an opaque (per-pixel) alpha channel which will overwrite all your calls to ***set_alpha()***
- one which has no per-pixel alpha and thus will honor your ***set_alpha()***

Hope this will help!

Comment: I'm thinking I'll just subclass pygame.Surface - seems like the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have read that the convert()-function disables image's alpha.
What I know is:

Using the convert()-function speeds up blitting the image for screen-big images on my computer to around 150 FPS with a colour depth of 16 bit.

```
image = image.convert()#video system has to be initialed
```